# MySQL Query - Pending Friends Approval / Relationship between user & friends

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relationship

I have two tables:

- g_relationships (id,request_id,receiver_id,status,approved)
- g_users (which contains: id,username,...)

I have a hard time making a query that adds a temporary column, checks whether userid: 4 exists in request_id or receiver_id column, and take the other userid and fetch username from g_users and adds it to the temporary column.

For example: Lets say I have userid 4. I then want to select g_relationships, and left join with g_users, and add a column that checks whether my userid (4) is in the request_id or the receiver_id column, and takes userid which isn't mine, and checks which username that it is and fills the new column with.

For example: a correct result would look like this: (if I were to receive a friend request)

| id | request_id | receiver_id | status | approved | friend(new_column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | friend | no | Neo |

But if I was the one who sent the friend request it would look like this

| id | request_id | receiver_id | status | approved | friend(new_column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | friend | no | Neo |

In other words, the query should always check in what column that I don't appear , and take that userid, and check against g_users table and place the username from there into friend column.

This is what I have come up with so far, but this only checks then request_id is not 4, and also doesn't populate the temporary column "friend" with the username :/

```sql
    SELECT *, ("friend" = CASE WHEN request_id != 4 THEN  END) as friend_id  
    FROM `g_relationships`
    LEFT JOIN g_users
    ON g_relationship.request_id = g_users.id
    WHERE request_id = 4 OR receiver_id = 4
    AND status = "friend"
    AND approved = "no"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Desired results are of little help without the sample data they are derived from, add a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this two ways.  Both use an extra JOIN to the g_users table.  The first is a single query that gets you the output you're looking for, while the the second is (in my opinion) more readable but uses a UNION and is technically two queries.

They give the same output.

Sandbox setup:

```
CREATE TABLE g_relationships (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    request_id INT,
    receiver_id INT,
    status VARCHAR(10),
    approved VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE g_users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO g_users (id, username) VALUES
(1, "Jane"),
(2, "Bob"),
(3, "Sally"),
(4, "Frank");

INSERT INTO g_relationships (id, request_id, receiver_id, status, approved) VALUES
(1, 1, 3, "Friend", "No"),
(2, 1, 4, "Enemy", "No"),
(3, 4, 3, "Friend", "Yes"),
(4, 4, 2, "Friend", "Yes");
```

Mega-JOIN:

```
SELECT u.id, rel.request_id, rel.receiver_id, rel.status, rel.approved, u2.username AS FriendName
FROM g_relationships AS rel
JOIN g_users AS u
  ON (rel.request_id = u.id OR rel.receiver_id = u.id)
JOIN g_users AS u2
  ON (rel.request_id = u2.id OR rel.receiver_id = u2.id)
WHERE u.id != u2.id
  AND u.id = 4;
```

UNION:

```
SELECT u.id, rel.request_id, rel.receiver_id, rel.status, rel.approved, u2.username AS FriendName
FROM g_relationships AS rel
JOIN g_users AS u
  ON rel.request_id = u.id
JOIN g_users AS u2
  ON rel.receiver_id = u2.id
WHERE u.id = 4

UNION

SELECT u.id, rel.request_id, rel.receiver_id, rel.status, rel.approved, u2.username AS FriendName
FROM g_relationships AS rel
JOIN g_users AS u
  ON rel.receiver_id = u.id
JOIN g_users AS u2
  ON rel.request_id = u2.id
WHERE u.id = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer! The UNION solution solved it perfectly! Very appreciated that you would take time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It will join on either of the two ids.

```
...
LEFT JOIN g_users ON ( g_relationship.request_id = g_users.id OR
                       g_relationship.receiver_id = g_users.id )  
WHERE g_users.id = 4
```